# Why can't I update or delete certain records in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-delete

I am having a weird issue in SQL Server 2014. I cannot update or delete *certain* rows from a table.

I can insert rows fine, and select them, but when I try to update or delete a row, I get a timeout error. It is also strange, that some of the rows can be updated, while others cannot. The table is small, only a few thousand rows, and it's hard to see a pattern with which rows can and cannot be updated, but it seems the more recently inserted rows cannot be deleted/updated.

There are no triggers on the table and the table has a primary key.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Offtopic. Not really a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Comment: You say you get a timeout error, which system are you seeing this in? I don't believe SQL has it's own timeout, it'll just run forever.

Comment: How are you trying to delete the rows?  What kind of permissions do you have to perform DML on the table in question?  Are there any foreign key references? More information is better than less.  Right now the only answer anyone can give you is , "Because".

Comment: How do you know there are no locks?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm interested in this too. Sounds an awful lot like blocking to me.

Comment: Sql Server Management Studio gives the timeout error. 
When trying to delete/update, I have tried writing sql statements in SSMS and have tried in the SSMS gui, both give the same timeout error. There are no foreign key references.

Comment: It did turn out to be blocking. We just found out about the sp_who2 command, which showed blocking. Earlier we were relying on the Activity Monitor, which did not show blocking. Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be another process locking those rows. We found out by running SQL Server's sp_who2 utility.

The people on [the DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136506/why-cant-i-update-or-delete-certain-records-in-sql-server) had some good suggestions for problems like this.